# Solc compile contracts with 5.0.0

Tags: solc

I was following this guide for compiling my contracts [How To: Compile a Solidity Smart Contract Using Node.js](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-compile-a-solidity-smart-contract-using-node-js-51ea7c6bf440) but "solc.compile(input, 1)" is not working anymore. I have problems understanding how to fix this...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53604799/solidity-v0-5-0-compiler-error-invalid-callback-specified/53620065#53620065.

Answer (score 2):

you need to see the new document. [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solc-js#example-usage-without-the-import-callback)

that article is too old.

```js
var solc = require('solc')

var input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'test.sol': {
            content: 'contract C { function f() public { } }'
        }
    },
    settings: {
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': [ '*' ]
            }
        }
    }
}

var output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)))

// `output` here contains the JSON output as specified in the documentation
for (var contractName in output.contracts['test.sol']) {
    console.log(contractName + ': ' + output.contracts['test.sol'][contractName].evm.bytecode.object)
}
```