# Not able to get rid of error from solc-js "AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified."

Tags: solc

```
const path=require('path');
const fs=require('fs');
const solc=require('solc');
const InboxPath=path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','Inbox.sol');
const source=fs.readFileSync(InboxPath,'utf8');
solc.compile(source,1);
```

Here is my error:

```
kowsik@kowsik:~/Desktop/etherium_project$ node compile.js
assert.js:43
  throw new errors.AssertionError(obj);
  ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback specified.
    at wrapCallback (/home/kowsik/Desktop/etherium_project/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:16:5)
    at runWithReadCallback (/home/kowsik/Desktop/etherium_project/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:42:26)
    at compileStandard (/home/kowsik/Desktop/etherium_project/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:83:14)
    at Object.compileStandardWrapper (/home/kowsik/Desktop/etherium_project/node_modules/solc/wrapper.js:90:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/kowsik/Desktop/etherium_project/compile.js:7:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
```

Comment: See https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/64456/solc-compile-contracts-with-5-0-0.

Comment: this could be a old solidity error, version 5 is a breaking change.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are using new version of solidity (currently mine is 0.6.1): Then the below code should work for you!**

*Here simply data format is changes as the format you are using is not supported in newer version soo we defined the datatype for o/p and convert json data to string.*

```
 module.exports = solc.compile(
  JSON.stringify({
    language: "Solidity",
    sources: {
      "lottery.sol": {
        content: source
      }
    },
    settings: {
      outputSelection: {
        "*": {
          "*": ["evm", "bytecode"]
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an older solc version for example "solc": "^0.4.25"

Comment: the command is : npm install --save solc@0.4.25